# Formatting date in PHP

Tags: php

Formatting the date below is not working.  The date_published after the echo date_published is in this format:  Sat, 15 Sep 2012 10:10:37 -0400

The second echo, echoes nothing.

```
$date_published = $abc[$z]['pubDate'];
echo $date_published;
$date_published = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$date_published);
echo $date_published;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`strtotime()`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

`$date_published = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($date_published));`

[`date()`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) expects a unix timestamp as the second parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Use `strtotime()`:

```
$date_published = $abc[$z]['pubDate'];
echo $date_published;
$date_published = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($date_published));
echo $date_published;
```

Answer (score 1):

This script:

```
$date_published = 'Sat, 15 Sep 2012 10:10:37 -0400';
printf("date_published=%s\n", $date_published);
$time = strtotime($date_published);
printf("time=%s\n", $time);

$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$time);
printf("date=%s\n", $date);

# if you are using PHP 5.2 or greater:
$dt = new DateTime($date_published);
$date = $dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
printf("date=%s\n", $date);
```

produces this output:

```
date_published=Sat, 15 Sep 2012 10:10:37 -0400
time=1347718237
date=2012-09-15 07:10:37
date=2012-09-15 10:10:37
```

Note that `date()` is displaying the time to my local timezone (PDT or -07:00), but `DateTime()` is displaying the time in the original timezone (-04:00).

Comment: Wow, that's some high praise. I hope I can live up to it! :)

Answer (score 0):

For formatting a date using php, you need to use date function  which accepts  date format and timestamp  as arguments.

In the above example you need to generate timestamp for $date_published using strtotime() and pass it as a second argument in date function.

eg $date_published = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($date_published));